# ¿Cómo se puede hacer un mapa dinámico web en html y javascript de algún estado o país?

Tags: javascript, html5, web, aplicación-web

Me surgió la idea de hacer un mapa de los municipios de un estado, el cual quiero que muestre información respecto a cada uno de ellos, pero no se por donde empezar y mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo hacerlo? o ¿Que herramientas necesito?

**Ejemplos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui hay un mapa similar a lo que busco: https://www.inegi.org.mx/

Comment: Hola, se puede hacer svg container, con las etiquetas svg y path, podría darte mas información si agregas mas detalles y lo que has intentado por favor.

Comment: En si, no se por donde empezar, es una idea que me surgió y quiero desarrollar,  pero no se como, he visto muchos mapas dinámicos, anexo sitio web https://www.inegi.org.mx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar el api de google maps. Hay otros proveedores open source, pero no se comparan con google maps

Aqui como puedes empezar

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Puedes agregar marcadores dentro del mapa 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Puedes agregar tambien mapas de calor
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

Incluso agregar imagenes o modales o textboxes dentro de tu mapa
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

Espero te sirva, ya que tu pregunta es muy general. Sin embargo podrias empezar checando la documentación.

Hover con fusiontables:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles

Comment: En el mapa que subi, cada pais se pinta al hacer hover y eso es lo que quiero

Comment: Edite mi comentario, checa la ultima liga. Como lo comente, es cuestion de que explores las herramientas